# firefox drag and drop image to file explorer

Tags: windows-10, firefox, windows-explorer, drag-and-drop

Since Firefox v68 the **drag and dropping of an image** from the browser (firefox.exe) to **Windows File Explorer** or Desktop (explorer.exe) is **not working** anymore.

> What I tried so far:

- Tried turning it off and on again *didn't work*
- Started firefox in safemode with no add-ons *didn't work*
- Started windows in safe mode and then started firefox in safemode with no add-ons *didn't work*
- Drag n Drop + holding Ctrl key didn't work Drag n Drop + holding Alt key *didn't work*
- Created a new profile *didn't work*
- Re-installed v68 *didn't work*
- uninstalled and erased ALL firefox files, then installed v68 *didn't work*
- Installed v68 on a fresh install of Windows *didn't work*
- Installed a fresh copy of Windows on a freshly assembled computer and made a fresh installation of v68 Firefox *didn't work*
- Reverting to Firefox v67 *did work !!*

So after investigation it must be an issue with the Firefox 68 update.

Comment: Thanks-- I didn't know you could drag/drop images. However, I find they can be dropped into MS Paint or other image-editing tool without removing that security feature.

Comment: @dsstorefile1 Firefox runs as **GUSTAV\rogez** and **rogez** is an administrator but I'm not sure how Win10 runs elevation as the way UAC works has been changed since Win8. Is a user with admin privileges still an administrator before the UAC prompt is approved?

Comment: @dsstorefile1 that is a very interesting article I didn't see before. thanks for that, indeed my UAC is set on "never notify" but my "Windows Metro Apps" are working again since the last 1903 upgrade, so I assumed UAC was switched on automatically by the upgrade, but now I know it's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by a new launcher process which forces Firefox at a medium integrity level when it detects that it is running at a high integrity level, as is the case when User Account Control (UAC) is disabled in Windows. Processes with lower integrity levels cannot send data to higher integrity levels (such as Windows Explorer when running as Administrator). There are several workarounds provided by Mozilla:

1. Enable the default level of UAC in Windows
2. Keep UAC disabled and use workarounds. For example, to copy an image to the desktop, instead of drag-and-drop, use right-click > Copy Image, then right-click > Paste on the desktop.
3. Keep UAC disabled and change how Firefox starts up by adding a command-line switch to your Firefox shortcut (-no-deelevate). For example `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -no-deelevate`
   This bypasses the reduction of Firefox's privilege level.
4. Keep UAC disabled and disable the launcher process, which both bypasses the reduction of Firefox's privilege level and reduces protection against DLL injection (least secure). This can be done by going to `about:config` in the URL bar and setting `browser.launcherProcess.enabled` to `False`

Sources: 
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/windows-administrator-launcher-process-error-fix

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1264292?page=2#answer-1238489

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1264413#answer-1239116

Answer (score 0):

After some research I found the issue was caused by a **new security feature** that was released to the general public in Firefox 68. You can **disable the new feature** by adding this command to your Firefox (taskbar) shortcut:

```
-no-deelevate
example: "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -no-deelevate
```

watch out for the quotes when there are spaces in your startup path. After restarting Firefox with this command the problem was solved!